# Move FPGA SOM to opposite side of 4-layer PCB

Tags: fpga, high-speed, routing

Recently I have started working on a project where want to use a (Zynq Ulteascale+ FPGA) SoM.

The device is equipped with fine-pitch mezzanine connectors, over which I want to use the USB3, Ethernet and other peripheral functionally. Normally I would use a signal-gnd-power-signal stack on my four layer pcb, where the SOM would be placed on the GND side. So far so good.

Physical constraints might force me to switch the SOM over to the other side. This started me thinking; what would the implications be of such a switch? Especially of impedance controlled transmission lines coming out of the mezzanine connector, crossing the power plane and continuing on the top side.

1. Would this, with proper stitching GND via's close to the connector al be good?
2. The transmission lines should cross the board preferably (very) close to the connector, I assume? Would a Via-in-pad be useful here?
3. can somebody point me to some literature on this topic?

Comment: Stitching vias for what ? you only have one GND layer. You need stitching capacitors between GND and POWER, so you can route the transmission lines over POWER plane. Or just do it well, and use two Ground planes and stitching vias at the signal vias.

Comment: I would not recommend vias in Ethernet/USB lines.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent why? You need to design/specify them for the correct characteristic impedance, but both USB and Ethernet are, by design, very robust against slight mismatches, so even with mediocre effort, you'll make a working connection; a well-designed via pair will be much better matched than any point at which you go from pcb trace to connector, which you must do, anyways. It does take following guidelines, but if vias in USB lines were impossible, you'd see a lot fewer affordable USB devices.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for the response. We are on the same page here - sure it is possible. But it is not a trivial design task and requires a step-up in PCB capeabilitys. You can get away with standard FR-4 if you run your differential pairs (Some USB2.x/3.x or Ethernet 100/1000MBit) on a single layer. Not recommendet for sure. But if you also want to switch layers on this "cheap FR4", you are asking for trouble. So by using vias for differential pairs, you - in my opinion - go with higher priced pcbs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller My next point is: If your "external design" - e.g. connector layout and HMI and what not - is not fixed/somewhat fluent, i would tend to move the connectors onto "the correct layer", instead of jumping layers with vias. I mean: Sure you can do vias and so on, and with a powerfull CAD-package it is not a problem. If you want it to work "for sure" and be done: Maybe this is the easier route.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The third reason is kind of the second: I like it simple. You are asking for trouble - which can be overcome - when switching these signals through power planes close to a power hungry FPGA/CPU/SOM there can be signal integrity issues. Sure: You can design it, put in the effort, do your research, follow all guidelines - not a problem and for sure an accomplischment. Or you can route it "on the correct layer" and be done in 10minutes. But: As i said - we are on the same page, besides looking from different perspectives.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent  Good points! Of course, when you can easily make it so that you don't change layers: don't change layers.